# Why is rebirth considered as a curse?

Tags: rebirth

Why do the scriptures consider enlightenment as the state when one is not born into the mortal coil once again? While the mortal form does endure a lot of sufferings, being able to live and breathe is in itself a great blessing.

Comment: "being able to live and breathe is in itself a great blessing" - what if you did not HAVE to live and breathe in order to be happy ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following which shows that scriptures don't consider rebirth as a curse:

**Rigveda 10.59.6-7:**

> O Blissful Ishwar, Please provide us again healthy eyes and other
>   sense organs in next birth. Please provide us powerful vitality, mind,
>   intellect, valor again and again in next births. We achieve bliss in
>   this life and future lives. May we keep looking up to your glory
>   always. Keep us in peace with your blessings. O Ishwar, you provide us
>   space, earth and other elements again and again so that our sense
>   organs function. You provide us the ability to have good health and
>   enjoy life in every birth. You make us strong again and again in
>   various births.

**Yajurveda 4.15:**

> Whenever we take birth, may our deeds be such that we get a pure mind,
>   long life, good health, vitality, intellect, strong sense organs and a
>   powerful body. In next life also, keep us away from bad deeds and
>   indulge us in noble actions.

**Atharvaveda 7.67.1:**

> May we get healthy sense and work organs in next life as well. May I
>   am full of vitality. May I have spiritual wealth and knowledge of
>   Ishwar and vedic concepts again and again. May we be selfless for
>   welfare of world in next lives again and again. May our deeds be noble
>   so that we get human life and always get purity of mind and actions so
>   that we can worship you and achieve salvation.

**Atharvaveda 5.1.2:**

> One who conducts noble actions obtains noble lives in next births with
>   strong body and sharp intellect. Those who conduct bad deeds get birth
>   in lower species. To experience the fruits of past actions is natural
>   trait of soul. After death, the soul resides in Vayu, Jala, Aushadhi
>   etc and again enters the womb to take next birth.

**Yajurveda 19.47:**

> There are two paths for the soul. One path Pitriyan provides birth
>   again and again through union of father and mother, good and bad
>   deeds, happiness and sorrow. The other path of Devayana frees the soul
>   from cycle of birth and death and provides bliss of salvation. The
>   whole world reverberates with both these paths. And after both, the
>   soul again takes birth as progeny of father and mother.

**Rigveda 1.24.1-2:**

> Question: Whom do we consider the most pure? Who is the most
>   enlightened one in entire world. Who provides us mother and father
>   again in the world after gifting us ultimate bliss or Mukti? Answer:
>   The self-enlightening, eternal, ever-free Ishwar alone is most pure.
>   He alone provides us mother and father again in the world after
>   gifting us ultimate bliss or Mukti.

**Rig Veda 10.4.57.4**

> ā ta etu mana punah kratve dakshāya jīvase, Jyok ca sūryam drishe.
>
> “May your spirit return again, to perform pure acts for exercising
>   strength, and to live long to see the sun.”

[Refer](http://veda.wikidot.com/samsara) this where it explains that the person himself decides when to exit this cycle of births.

**Breaking the Bond Of Samsara**

> The chains that tie you to this wheel of Samsara or Bhava-Chakra or
>   round of births and deaths, are your desires. So long as you desire
>   objects of this world, you must come back to this world in order to
>   possess and enjoy them. But, when all your desires for the mundane
>   objects cease, then the chains are broken and you are free. You need
>   not take any more births. You attain Moksha or the final emancipation.
>
> You wander in this Samsara as you think that you are different from
>   the Lord. If you unite yourself with Him through meditation and Yoga,
>   you will obtain immortality and eternal bliss. Cut the bonds of Karma
>   through Knowledge of the Eternal and enjoy the Supreme Peace of the
>   Atman, thy innermost Self and Inner Ruler. You will be freed from the
>   round of births and deaths. Freed from sin, freed from passion, you
>   will become a Jivanmukta or liberated sage. You will see the Self in
>   the self and see the Self as all.